# Slim return response with status 400 and redirect

Tags: php, slim

Hi I am trying to return a status code of 400 if a post request fails and then redirect the user back to the page they ent the post from.

I have tried the following examples:

```
return $response->withRedirect('/view/companies', 400);
```

this just returns a white page

```
return $response->withStatus(400);
```

this just returns a white page

```
return $response->withJson([], 400);
```

this just returns a white page with this at the top
[image]

```
return $response->withRedirect('/view/companies');
```

this returns the user back to the page but doesn't through the 400 error.

Comment: See this similar issue: https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/2355

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections

> HTTP redirects are responses with a status code of 3xx.

Thus a redirect with a status code of `400` is not possible (although it worked in Slim up to version 3.9, see https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/2355).

Comment: Would you suggest just redirect and don't through an error?

Comment: @Lukerayner Yes, at least that's what I did when I came across this.

Comment: Ok thank you for the help! I display an error message anyway so it's not a problem.

Comment: I suggest you display an error and do not redirect the user. From [Status Code Definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3): `This class of status code indicates that further action needs to be taken by the user agent in order to fulfill the request.`, but as you described, *the request can not be processed*, not even by taking additional steps. So it seems the appropriate response code would be a 4xx.